# Parsing complex XML in VB.NET

Tags: xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

I have an ugly block of XML that I am trying to parse in VB.net.
Basically, I need to find a particular node, and then start grabbing all the info in that particular node that is hidden a few nodes deeper.  I can construct something to find the node I want and select its child nodes into a nodelist.  I can then loop through that nodelist and pull attributes from that nodelist, but I can't seem to find a way to make a new nodelist based upon a selected node.  I have searched and failed to find an answer, so I think I am doing something fundamentally stupid.  I basically need to grab all of the info in the `<SixithLayer>` and deeper and parse it up, but I have only been able to get information from the `<SixithLayer>`

My Code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml
Public Class Form1
    Sub ExampleXML()
        Dim my_XML_doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
        Dim first_node_list As XmlNodeList
        Dim second_node_list As XmlNodeList
        my_XML_doc.Load("C:\temp\xmlExample.xml")
        first_node_list = my_XML_doc.SelectNodes("/FirstLayer/SecondLayer/ThirdLayer//FourthLayer[@Type='Type D']//FifthLayer/*")
        For Each node In first_node_list
            Dim grab_first_layer_info = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value
            second_node_list = node.SelectNodes("ImportantInfo")
            For Each node2 In second_node_list
                Dim grab_second_layer_info = node.Attributes.GetNamedItem("Name").Value
                'Some more for looping here to get all the attributes and and innerXML values hidden in here
                'unless there is a better way to quickly grab stuff that might be a variable
                'number of nodes deeper with varied names.
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

My XML

```
<FirstLayer>
    <SecondLayer>
        <ThirdLayer>
            <FourthLayer Type="Type A" Name="FirstName"></FourthLayer>
            <FourthLayer Type="Type B" Name="SecondName"></FourthLayer>
            <FourthLayer Type="Type C" Name="ThirdName"></FourthLayer>
            <FourthLayer Type="Type D" Name="FourthName">
                <FifthLayer>
                    <SixthLayer Type="Step" Name="First">
                        <SomeJunk></SomeJunk>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="1stImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>500</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                            <MoreStuff Flavor="Purple" Look="Chocolate">
                                <Value>29</Value>
                            </MoreStuff>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="2ndImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>TRUE</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="3rdImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>Cat</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                    </SixthLayer>
                    <SixthLayer Type="Step" Name="Second">
                        <SomeJunk></SomeJunk>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="1stImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>500</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="2ndImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>TRUE</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                        <ImportantInfo Name="3rdImportantStuff">
                            <StoreValue>
                                <Value>Cat</Value>
                            </StoreValue>
                        </ImportantInfo>
                    </SixthLayer>
                </FifthLayer>
            </FourthLayer>
        </ThirdLayer>
    </SecondLayer>
</FirstLayer>
```

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Fixed it so that it so that the second loop works per the comments below.  Not sure how I managed to miss that so thoroughly.  Still curious if there is a better way to grab all of the attribute and innertext information that is in `<ImportantStuff>` and beyond besides looping deeper and deeper, but this is a pretty good start.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use LINQ to XML instead of old XmlDocument. What exactly would you like to take from the XML?

Comment: Don't put the forward slash in front of `SeventhNode`.  That forces it to go back up to the root element.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, as nice as LINQ is, it's a proprietary Microsoft technology.  Many people, like myself, prefer XPath.  XPath is very useful for many reasons.  The fact that it is a standard technology employed by many other tools and languages, not least among them.  You can use XPath via some extension methods on the `XElement` class, but there's certainly nothing wrong with `XmlDocument`.

Comment: I'm confused by what you are trying to do/what you are having trouble with.  Your first XPath select, in your example, grabs all of the `SixthLayer` elements.  Is that what you intended it to do?  Then you try to select the `SeventhNode`, as if that were the name of a sub-element under the `SixthLayer` element.  There is no such sub-element, so even if you didn't precede it with a slash, it still won't find anything based on your example.

Comment: If, for instance, you changed that second select to `second_node_list = node.SelectNodes("ImportantInfo")`, that would work to select all of the `ImportantInfo` elements under the current `SixthLayer` element, but it's not clear from your question if that's what you are attempting to do

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I fixed it so that it gets the second nodelist.  Not sure how I missed that.  I think I might have made a mistake earlier and then made a number of bad syntax assumptions from that.  The only other question I have is, philosophically, is there a more sane way to grab the attribute and final innertext information other than looping deeper and deeper?  I basically need to pull out everything in `<ImportantStuff>` and deeper, and spit it out into something readable.  Basically, I need all attributes and terminating innertext.

Comment: If there is only one sub-element by each name (e.g. `StoreValue` and `MoreStuff`), then there's no need to loop.  If you need to grab any sub-element, no matter how deep, you can get it with `SelectSingleNode` (e.g. `Dim v As String = node.SelectSingleNode("StoreValue/Value").InnerText`).  If, however, there may be multiple `StoreValue` elements, for instance, then obviously you'd need to loop through them to get them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the way you are doing it is the easiest way. Even though it's kind of a pain, it's quicker than writing your own parser.

It might improve the code's readability if you move the inner for loop to another sub, and then probably use a separate sub for the inside of that loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at various options and choose the best and easy approach.

I searched for LINQ to Xml and found interesting article which talks parsing XML. You can apply where clause in LINQ query as alternate solution.

Here is the article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-write-queries-on-xml-in-namespaces

Hope this helps. Thank you!